# Nginx TLS-SNI: Use hostname dependent SSL for HTTPS

Tags: nginx

I need to use two different ssl certs with nginx pointing to the same app.

https://domain1.com points to 1.1.1.1
https://domain2.com points to 1.1.1.1
.
.
.
.
https://domainN.com points to 1.1.1.1

Tried the following:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain1.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}



server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain1.com;
    root /app/dist;

    index index.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/d1/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/d1/private.key;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }

}

server {
listen 80;
server_name domain2.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}



server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain2.com;
    root /app/dist;

    index index.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/d2/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/d2/private.key;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }

}
```

This doesn't work, it just loads the first cert resulting in invalid cert when accessed using the second domain.

The domain certs can't be combined.
I can't spin two different instances for nginx as the case needs to help me out with n-Domains pointing to same IP preferably using one nginx server.

Is there a way out?

Comment: Half your `server_name` directives are correct and half of them are wrong. The `https://` bit is not part of the server name. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I have corrected it. But I did try it with the corrected name before posting this. It would just load the first block's SSL cert. I think this is just not possible because the host name will itself be encrypted and the correct cert will be needed to decrypt it which would again need the hostname. So its a never ending loop like scenario. Sad how somethings can't be done with software. :(

Comment: `nginx` implements SNI (see [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni)) to present the correct certificate for the requested host name. If the first `server` block is being used - it means that the requested host name is not an **exact** match for the value of the `server_name` directive. Use `nginx -T` to test your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. It is the exact match, i have just changed the port from 443 ssl to 80 and commented the ssl files line and it loads the http version just fine. I will double check and get back to you. Also, I am using let's encrypt wildcard certs.

Comment: Thanks a tonne!!!! TLS SNI was disabled. It worked! :) Software indeed does allow you to do anything. Can't be happier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) for pointing out just the right stuff!

So, to setup nginx to use different cert-key pair for domains pointing to the same nginx we have to rely on TLS-SNI (Server Name Indication), where the domain name is sent un-encrypted text as a part of the handshake. This helps nginx to decide which cert-key pair to use for the incoming secure request.

More can be read about SNI [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni).

Moving on to the configuration.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain1.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}



server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain1.com;
    root /app/dist;
    index index.html;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/d1/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/d1/private.key;

    location / {    
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}


server {
listen 80;
server_name domain2.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}



server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain2.com;
    root /app/dist;
    index index.html;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/d2/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/d2/private.key;

    location / {    
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

The above config forwards HTTP (80) for both domain1 and domain2 to respective HTTPS (443) server blocks, where respective cert-key pairs are loaded.
The HTTPS (443) request is handled directly.
nginx decides which block to hit by picking the server name using SNI.